# Hibernate two date result

Tags: hql

Hibernate Between getting wrong result.If i use date 14 to 18. I am getting result 12 to 16

```
enter code here
   **  query = "Select *\n" +
            "from Schedule\n" +
            "Where [Date] between :fromDate and :toDate\n"**
```

Comment: can you explain your question a little bit?

Comment: yes. if i use date between query in mssql studio mangement result is right.but when hql query result get wrong Eg. ill use 2019-01-14 to 2019-01-18 result coming 14,15,16,17,18 sql management.but hibernate result is 12,13,14,15,16